# Replace error in IE10 but not in IE8 or Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I have a form written in Cold Fusion.  When I test the form in IE8 or Firefox, I have no problems.  When I test the form in IE10, it gives the following error:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 8 May 2013 18:15:47 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'
>   Line: 7
>   Char: 10560
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://www.mysite.com/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/adapter/yui/ext-yui-adapter.js

When I look at the code surrounding character 10560 in the js file, it shows

```
 {return this.replace(a,"")}
```

Why is this happening?  Is IE10 buggy?  (No, that is not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: It's probably because `this` is not an instance of `String`. We can't tell more from one line of code. Also, you have compatibility mode turned on so IE10 behaves like IE7.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx) string.replace should work fine in IE10, and it would be a big suprise if it did'nt, so `this` is probably not a string ?

Comment: Can you give url for the full .js or a testcase on jsfiddle? And seems you are using IE10 in IE7 mode (states MSIE 7.0 on user agent).

Comment: I am not trying to debug the yui javascript file.  I am trying to determine why it is failing in IE10.

Comment: isn't that the definition of debugging?

Comment: Here is the full function that includes the replace:   String.prototype.trim=function(){var a=/^\s+|\s+$/g;return function(){return this.replace(a,"")}}

Comment: That's a polyfill for trim(), and you're probably trying to trim() something other than a string then ?

Comment: the yui file exists on a coldfusion server on my shared hosting service.  There is nothing I will be able to do with the yui file where it is.

Comment: Still doesn't answer why it is only failing in IE10.

Comment: Where do I change the mode that IE is running in?

Comment: Aboutbox shows Version 10.0.9200.16540.

Comment: @Richard Press F12 on your IE10. Will pop a Developer Tool. On the top part will have some text like "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode". Click on them and pick `Internet Explorer 10` and `Internet Explorer 10 Standards` on them. Test. Then pick and change both to `Internet Explorer 7` and `Internet Explorer 7 Standards` and test again.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not a string.

To make sure it will work, you can change from

```
this.replace(a,"")
```

to

```
this.toString().replace(a,"")`
```

or use `.toString()` in the var when it's still on your control, so you don't need to actually change YUI .js (bad because if you need to update it someday, you might forget and have the problem again).

By the way, if `a` is not a string, it is already converted to string so no need to worry about it.

See this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3Cd4d/ (look at Dev Tools' Console)

Comment: This does not answer why it is failing with identical inputs in IE10 (IE7) and not in IE8 and Firefox.

Comment: @Richard With the info you provided, that works. If you want a better help, provide us a test case. This might be because you are in IE7 quirks (bad DOCTYPE) or whatever other obscure reason we can't foresee without a test case.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> - Why would this be causing problems?  My page is written in Cold Fusion.  How would I provide a test case in jsfiddle?

Comment: We don't need all your code, just the code that fails, which is what jsfiddle is for (look the example I did).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  This is what was causing it.

I had a SELECT with multiple specified.

In my validation function, I was trimming the value of this field.  Apparently, IE10/IE7 did not like this.

Thank you all for your assistance, and to the person who suggested that I was not passing a string.

Comment: That's why I said to make us a testcase. We would've never guessed it with just that line of JS :/